# Missing package.appxmanifest in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I need to build a URI handler, which requires registering the entry point in the package manifest. This [website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-uri-activation) tells how to do it, saying:

> In the Solution Explorer, double-click package.appxmanifest to open
>   the manifest designer. Select the Declarations tab and in the
>   Available Declarations drop-down, select Protocol and then click Add.

... but my Visual Studio (I have the free version of 2017) does not have the `package.appxmanifest` anywhere in solution explorer (my project is a .NET framework forms application). My searches do not illuminate a method to make this thing appear.

Can anyone offer how to get the rascal to appear?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, now I feel dumb. All you have to do is go to the Project Menu, add item option, and then you add a package manifest. Turns out Windows Forms apps don't have a manifest by default.